# xclip not getting stdin from pexpect, or pexpect not sending?

Tags: python, expect, xclip

This

```py
import pexpect

def run(cmd, stdin):
    child = pexpect.spawn(cmd, encoding='utf-8')
    child.send(stdin)
    child.sendeof()

run('xclip -selection clipboard', 'lol')
```

should copy string `lol` into my clipboard, so that I paste it around by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

But, instead, I get the behaviour of `echo -n '' | xclip -selection clipboard`  i.e. the behaviour of passing empty file as STDIN into `xclip`.

Why?

---

**UPDATE**

This prints `lollxl` instead of just `lxl`:

```py
import pexpect

def run(cmd, stdin):
    child = pexpect.spawn(cmd, encoding='utf-8')
    child.send(stdin)
    child.sendeof()
    child.sendeof()
    x = child.read()
    child.wait()
    return x

x = run("sed --expression='s/o/x/g'", 'lol')
print(x)
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use pexpect for this at all, instead of purely standard-library functionality, as in `subprocess.Popen(['xclip', '-selection', 'clipboard'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate('lol')`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - only reason is to have a single `run` function that works with other commands that require STDIN, STDOUT and TTY piped.  If this can be done neatly without pexpect I'll happily leave it and never look back.

Comment: The only thing of what you listed that `subprocess` doesn't do that `pexpect` does is providing a tty (which frankly is not a very common need). Add `unbuffer` to the beginning of the command line, though, and that'll take care of your tty needs: `subprocess.Popen(['unbuffer', 'xclip', '-selection', 'clipboard'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate('lol')` -- though I don't recommend doing that when you don't _really_ need a tty, and xclip certainly doesn't require one.

Comment: Interesting (re: `unbuffer`).  Can it be done easily with pure Python using `import pty`?

Comment: I don't know -- would need to dig. That actually sounds like a worthwhile Stack Overflow question in and of itself.